# Best way to remap flat object into structured object in Java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am working with a technology called Verastream Host Integrator. Essentially VHI is a no-code/low-code GUI tool for working with mainframe data that that compiles into Java bindings.
One of the issues with VHI is that it can only output flat data. Here is an example:

```
public class VhiProcedureRecord {
    private String foo1;
    private String foo2;
    private String bar1;
    private String bar2;

    // constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

I am piping this output through a Spring Boot middleware layer and I want to remap this object into something that would look like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String foo1;
    private String foo2;

    // constructors, getters, and setters
}

public class Bar {
    private String bar1;
    private String bar2;

    // constructors, getters, and setters
}

public class MyRecord {
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;

    // constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

As you can see this requires splitting the fields in `VhiProcedureRecord` between `Foo` and `Bar`.
Doing this manually quickly becomes a huge pain.

The other problem with the output being flat is when the VHI output contains a list of data, it returns multiple records with duplicate fields, akin to what a SQL join would look like e.g.

```
public class VhiPetOwnershipRecord {
    private String ownerName;
    private String petName;

    // constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

The result of this procedure returns something akin to:

```
[
  {"ownerName": "JHuang", "petName": "Fido"},
  {"ownerName": "JHuang", "petName": "Spot"}
]
```

And I want to remap this into:

```
public class MyPetOwnershipRecord {
    private String ownerName;
    private List<String> petName;
}
```

Is there a way to use Jackson or something similar to do this sort of remapping automatically?

Keep in mind that `VhiProcedureRecord` is compiled by VHI, so that class can't be changed.

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of flat map files, you would be better off converting the flat map files to Java classes manually.  You're writing code, and that code needs to be tested.

Comment: I am not sure if by using Jackson annotations, you can achieve your goal but as you said you are not allowed to change `VhiProcedureRecord`, that option is not there. So, even if you write jackson custom serializer, you will still have to write custom code.

Comment: Got it. I figured as much.  
Yeah, I'm already doing these sorts of operations manually, just was wondering if there is a better way.